# MS SQL Server INSERT value If NULL

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

Good day

I have Table1:

```
COLUMN1    COLUMN2   Column3
----------------------------
1             A        K
2             NULL     K
3             NULL     D
...           ...      ...
```

I need

```
COLUMN1    COLUMN2   Column3
----------------------------
1             A        A
2             K        K
3             D        D
...           ...      ...
```

I am stuck with my code and I cannot understand why server tries to insert into COLUMN3 ?

Thanks for any opinions

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (COLUMN2)
    SELECT CLoumn3
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Column2 IS NULL;
```

Resulting error:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Column3', table 'TABLE1'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

This is only example original table have more columns.

Comment: You need `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`

Comment: So, you want to add new records or update existsing?

Comment: UPDATE Thanks to GOrdon

Comment: Just to clarify the original error you were getting - whenever you INSERT a row into a table, that row is inserted for *all* columns. If you don't specify a value for a column, SQL Server will try to insert a NULL. Some columns might be defined as not allowing NULL, so any insert will fail unless a value is specified for that column. In your case, you were specifying a value for Table1.COLUMN2, but not Table1.COLUMN3. It appears the COLUMN3 does not allow NULL so the insert failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want an `update`:

```
update table1
    set column2 = column3
    where column2 is null;
```

`insert` inserts *new rows* into a table.  `update` changes the values in existing rows.